# To compute the cell array of voronoi

Tags: python, matlab

I'm converting a Matlab code to python.I came across a function 'voronoin' in Matlab which gives vertices and cell array as an output. From my program I am only getting vertices. The cell array I am getting from my program is not matching with the one I got in Matlab.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi



def voronoi_volumes(points):
    v = Voronoi(points)
    print(v.vertices)
    for i, reg_num in enumerate(v.point_region):
        print(reg_num)
        indices = v.regions[reg_num]
        print(indices)


points = np.array([[ 0.4074,  0.4567],
                   [ 0.4529,  0.3162],
                   [ 0.0635,  0.0488],
                   [ 5, -45],
                   [ 5,  55],
                   [-45,  5],
                   [ 55,  5]])
k = voronoi_volumes(points)
```

In Matlab the output I have is:

```
[9,5,3,4,7]
[9,7,6,8]
[7,4,2,6]
[8,1,2,6]
[5,1,3]
[4,2,1,3]
[9,5,1,8]
```

In python the output I am getting is:

```
[7, 3, 1, 2, 5]
[7, 5, 4, 6]
[5, 2, 0, 4]
[6, -1, 0, 4]
[-1, 1, 3]
[-1, 0, 2, 1]
[7, 3, -1, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer iam getting in python is correct.Matlab and python have different indices. when i try to access vertices from the indices,iam getting same answers from both.